Pointwise convergence of $f_{n}(x) = \sin(\frac{x}{n})$
I'm trying to prove wether $f_{n}(x) = \sin(\frac{x}{n}), f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has pointwise convergence or not. My first idea is it is pointwise convergent to the function $f = 0$ because when I try to bound it I get $\|\sin(\frac{x}{n})|| \leq \frac{\|x||}{n}< \epsilon$, then by taking $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n_{0} >\frac{\|x||}{\epsilon}$, I get the inequality I'm looking for. That even gives me the hint that it is not uniformly convergent as the $n_{0}$ depends on x. But what if I take the sequence of points in $\mathbb{R},\ (x_{n})_{n} = \frac{\pi}{2}n$ then $f_{n}(x_{n}) = 1  \ \forall x \in\mathbb{R}$. So I don't know if the sequence taken as $(x_{n})$ is wrongly taken as an example or if it is indeed a non pointwise convergent sequence of functions.

The sequence ${x_n}$ that you have chosen works to show that given sequence of functions is not uniformly covergent.

But shouldn't it be if pointwise that for every x $f_{n}$goes to 0, only  that the $n_{0}$ depends on the x. But taken that sequence, it will always be $f_{n} = 1$ and won't approach 0?

Pointwise convergence is just "classic" convergence, with $x$ seen as a parameter. We have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{n}=0$ and since $\sin$ is continuous, this implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\sin(0)=0$.
So you are right about the pointwise convergence to $f(x)=0$. For the uniform convergence, you need to consider whether $s_n=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)|$ converges (as a sequence of numbers) to $0$. As you mentioned $s_n=f_n\left(n\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$, so the convergence is not uniform.

Note: my initial intuition was that the convergence is uniform since $\sin$ is periodic and bounded. This is wrong, and here is my attempt to understand why graphically. I wish I could add an animation or figure, but I don't have the skills.
A way to understand it visually: the graph of $f_n$ is obtained from the graph of $g(x)=\sin(x)$ by stretching it horizontally by a factor of $n$. Since $\sin(x)\simeq x$ near $0$, the graph of $g$ is almost a line near $0$ (on some interval $(-\delta,\delta)$), so the graph of $f_n$ can be approximated by a line that is more and more horizontal, but on a larger interval $(-n\delta,n\delta)$. This interval will eventually include any value of $x$, explaining the pointwise convergence to $0$.
However, for every $n$, there will still be points ($x_n=n\frac{\pi}{2}$ for example) far away from $0$ such that is not arbitrarily close to $0$ ($f_n(x_n)=1$), which is enough to prevents the uniform convergence.

Super clear! Thanks for the explanation and the insights!
